# Why does AngularJS shows that a scope variable is undefined in directive when it is defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angularJS directive that is called by:

```
<rpt-closing closing-begin-ts="null" closing-begin-ts="'2014-11-25 23:59:59'"></rpt-closing>
```

The directive code looks like:

```
  .directive('rptClosing',function(){
      return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
          closingBeginTs: '=',
          closingEndTs: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log('*******************************************');
          console.log('scope = ', scope);
          console.log('scope.closingBeginTs = ', scope.closingBeginTs);
          console.log('scope.closingEndTs = ', scope.closingEndTs);
          console.log('*******************************************');
        },
        template: '<div>BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>'
      };
    }
  )
```

This code works perfectly fine in [the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgxwqxun/). I can see the values of `scope.closingBeginTs` and `scope.closingEndTs` in the console output.

[image]

Comment: you didn't close your `rpt-closing` tag

Comment: I fixed that in the JSFiddle. Thanks. Still same result. In the code running locally on my machine., I had closed that tag. So that's not the issue.

Comment: try to complete the full flow like declaing controller then declare model bind that model with the directive .` =` is a two way binding it prefer model rather then value.

Comment: Why does the code in the question not match the fiddle?  There are two `closing-begin-ts` in the question.  What does your code look like where you are getting the error?  (Since the fiddle works fine.)

Comment: "*This code works perfectly fine in the jsFiddle."* - ok. When is it not working? How did you verify it is not working..?

Comment: In larger applications, I've experienced something similar. I'd assumed it had to do with how long it takes to instrument the application and the code within the directive evaluating before the scope above it has finished its bindings.

I solved the problem by moving to events, but I'd love to see other approaches.

Answer (score 6):

It logs as undefined because it is not defined. In the snippet you provided, both attributes are `closing-begin-ts`.

```
<rpt-closing closing-begin-ts="null" 
             closing-begin-ts="'2014-11-25 23:59:59'">  
</rpt-closing>
```

It should, of course, be:

```
<rpt-closing closing-begin-ts="null" 
             closing-end-ts="'2014-11-25 23:59:59'">  
</rpt-closing>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example I tried

```
<rpt-closing closing-begin-ts="null" 
         closing-begin-ts="'2014-11-25 23:59:59'"> </rpt-closing>
```

result is:
    **closingBeginTs** is *'null'* and **closingEndTs** is *'undefined'* as you are not using it in HTML

If you define both like this:

```
<rpt-closing closing-begin-ts="null" 
         closing-end-ts="'2014-11-25 23:59:59'"> </rpt-closing>
```

result is:
    **closingBeginTs** is *'null'* and **closingEndTs** is *''2014-11-25 23:59:59''* as you are not using it in HTML

You can try by passing attribute name also in scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the attribute name,

```
.directive('rptClosing',function(){
      return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
          closingBeginTs: '=closingBeginTs',
          closingEndTs: '=closingEndTs'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log('*******************************************');
          console.log('scope = ', scope);
          console.log('scope.closingBeginTs = ', scope.closingBeginTs);
          console.log('scope.closingEndTs = ', scope.closingEndTs);
          console.log('*******************************************');
        },
        template: '<div>BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>'
      };
    }
  )
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the variable name in isolate scope unless you are re-assigning it to a new variable name.